# virus detected while sending signed apk using gmail

Tags: android, apk, malware, virus

I am very confused why the gmail apk attachment showing as virus detected. Actually i implemented admob in android application and signed it.But while sending it getting issue.

[image]

If anyone have idea. Please reply.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless your apk is a virus, I guess it is a false postiive.

Comment: Thanks for reply.@user2310289,I am not understaning. could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after reviewing the code.because i was adding extra library as revmob with admob library.So need to remove extra code and unwanted library like admob,remob etc.

I hope this will help others.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you indeed didn't implement something nasty, it's clearly a false positive. As virus/malware keeps continuously changing, Google, as many other mail providers, implement Heuristics to catch all that bad stuff - so basically they are general pattern implementations. The good side of this approach is that it doesn't have to be implemented for each virus/malware specifically. The bad side is what you just experimented, a false positive.

Comment: Thanks i will check it what the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case what caused the virus detection was the word "**gif**" in a file name: slider_gif.html

I know it does not make any sense but when I renamed the file (removed the word "gif" ) the virus detection disapeared...

Answer (score 0):

Gmail restrict binary files such as *.exe *.so *.dll etc...

I suggest to use Google-drive to upload files than join the link in your mail message. this will allow you to share any binary files including the *.so in your apk archive.